# PDO - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, pdo

What is the problem in this function?

```
function journeygetLeadertalks($link, $journeyid)
{
    $thingResult = $link->prepare("SELECT `leadertalks` FROM `journey` WHERE journeyid=:journeyid");
    $thingResult->execute([
        "journeyid" => $journeyid
    ]);


    if($thingResult->fetchObject()->leadertalks == "NULL")
        return "imgs/noimg.png";
    else
        return $thingResult->fetchObject()->leadertalks;
}
```

Database picture:
[image]
This function works every time exepct when im using it for leadertalks and leadertalksImage, what can I do?

Comment: how bout posting the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `fetchObject()` twice. You're calling it once in the `if`, and then if the value doesn't match, you're calling it again in the `else`. But your query only returns one row, so the second `fetchObject()` returns `false`, and that's not an object. You need to save the result in a variable.

Also, if the query doesn't match anything at all, the initial `fetchObject()` will return `false`, so you should check for that as well.

```
$row = $thingResult->fetchObject();
if ($row && $row->leadertalks == "NULL") {
    return "imgs/noimg.png";
} else {
    return $row->leadertalks;
}
```

Comment: LOL, thanks man - I did such a stupid mistake tho. Have a nice day :3